# Ignis magnum biofuel fireplace

Tags: fireplace

[image]

Hi I recently installed this wall mount ignis magnum fireplace. The wallboard gets too hot to touch behind it. I was wondering if 1) heat paint behind would help 2) putting stainless steel sheet behind would help 3) i used plastic anchors to secure, would those become an issue? 4) am I too concerned?  Thoughts? Thanks Ed

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Do the installation instructions address this question?

Comment: Two hot to touch would concern me is this on the opposite side of the wall that feels two hot? With that said my wife thinks things are two hot to touch when I think they are warm (calluses v/s girly soft hands). Since it is listed I would think the mounting instructions would cover the expected heat range but I cannot download the instructions at my current location.